# Using SSL with docker containers

Tags: ssl, docker, ssl-certificate

I am having a trouble related with SSL certificates.
I have a server running service in a docker container, I installed Caddy and get the SSL certificate for the site. Now, from other server I want to consume the service with HTTPS, but I get:

```
x509: certificate signed by unknown authority exit status 1
```

And, it seems to be a common issue when using docker + SSL. What should I do? thanks

Comment: Which distribution are you using?

Comment: @RicardoBranco CentOS 7

Answer (score 1):

Install the **ca-certificates** package.